# Constraint formulation for an MILP optimization problem

Tags: optimization, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to formulate a constraint for an MILP optimization problem.

There are $N*N$ weighted points distributed on a 2D plane, each point denoted by its coordinate index $(i,j)$.

The decision variables are:

1. $N*N$ binary variables $z_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, i \in \{1,\ldots,N\}, j \in \{1,\ldots,N\} $;
2. 12 continuous variables $a_k, b_k, c_k \in \mathbb{R}, k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Denote the region bounded by four lines $ a_kx+b_ky+c_k = 0, k \in \{1,2,3,4\} $ as $S$.

The optimization problem is to select a region $S$ (determined by four lines) to cover points as few as possible while ensuring the weight sum of the covered points is greater than a threshold.

The constraint to formulate is: $z_{ij} = 1$ iff point $(i,j) \in S$ (i.e., point $(i,j)$ is covered by $S$) ; otherwise $z_{ij} = 0$. This constraint describes the relation between the binary decision variables $z_{ij}$ and continuous decision variables $a_k, b_k, c_k$. How do I formulate this constraint in terms of decision variables $z_{ij}$ and $a_k, b_k, c_k$ only, how do I formulate "iff"?

A sketch is attached to illustrate this:

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enforce $$z_{ij}=1\implies \bigwedge_{k=1}^4 (a_k i+b_k j+c_k\le 0) \quad \text{for all $i,j$},$$ and you can do so via linear big-M constraint $$a_k i+b_k j+c_k\le M_{ij1}(1-z_{ij})\quad\text{for all $i,j,k$}. \tag1\label1$$
Similarly, you can enforce $$z_{ij}=0\implies \bigvee_{k=1}^4 (a_k i+b_k j+c_k\ge 0) \quad \text{for all $i,j$}$$ via linear constraints
\begin{align}
-a_k i-b_k j-c_k &\le M_{ij2} z_{ijk} &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \tag2\label2 \\
1 - z_{ij} &\le \sum_k (1 - z_{ijk}) &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
If you want to avoid ambiguity of $z$ on the lines, introduce a small positive tolerance $\epsilon$ and add it to the left-hand side of \eqref{2}, as follows:
$$-a_k i-b_k j-c_k + \epsilon\le M_{ij2} z_{ijk}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions:       1) what do you mean by "f you want to avoid ambiguity of  on the lines, introduce a small positive tolerance  and add it to the LHS of the second big-M constraint"? "LHS" is? Could you explain it in detail?          2) for the current linear big-M constraint, there are still three types of variables: {a_k, b_k, c_k}, {z_ij}, and {i, j}. How could we reduce it to two types of variables only, i.e., in terms of {a_k, b_k, c_k}, {z_ij} only, not including {i, j}?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your first question.  For your second question, $i$ and $j$ are not variables.

Comment: Oh, I see. $i$ and $j$ need to be ranged over {1,...,N}. Thus, for linear big-M constraints $a_k i+b_k j+c_k\le M_{ij1} (1-z_{ij}).$, there are in fact N*N linear big-M constraints, not just one. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One concern left, what I really want to enforce is $z_{ij}=1 \rightarrow a_1i+b_1j+c_1 \leq 0 \wedge a_2i+b_2j+c_2 \leq 0 \wedge a_3i+b_3j+c_3 \leq 0 \wedge a_4i+b_4j+c_4 \leq 0$. The expression on the right side of $\rightarrow$ is conjunctive form. How do I deal with conjunction $\wedge$? Thanks.

Comment: Should I use the logical rule $z_{ij} =1 \rightarrow (a_1i+b_1j+c_1 \leq 0 \wedge a_2i+b_2j+c_2 \leq 0)$ is equivalent to $(z_{ij} =1 \rightarrow a_1i+b_1j+c_1 \leq 0) \wedge (z_{ij} =1 \rightarrow a_2i+b_2j+c_2 \leq 0)$. Then, for every $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, we can obtain a linear big-M constraint respectively $a_k i+b_k j+c_k\le M_{ij1}(1-z_{ij})$ (if $i,j$ is fixed here)

Comment: That is what my constraint $(1)$ does.  There is a separate constraint for each $k,i,j$.

Comment: It seems there is still an issue. One constraint I need to enforce  is "$z_{i j}=0 \Longrightarrow a_{1} i+b_{1} j+c_{1} \geq 0 \vee a_{2} i+b_{2} j+c_{2} \geq 0 \vee a_{3} i+b_{3} j+c_{3} \geq 0 \vee a_{4} i+b_{4} j+c_{4} \geq 0 $". I think this constraint cannot be transformed to 4 big-M constraints $-a_{k} i-b_{k} j-c_{k} \leq M_{i j 2} z_{i j}, k=1,2,3,4 $ as you wrote, due to the function of logical operator $\vee$.

Comment: I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: add a minor concern: what do you mean by "avoid ambiguity of z on the lines"? Introduce $\epsilon$ for the sake of avoiding roundoff errors?

Comment: It makes sense. I have two concerns. 1) So $z_{i j k}$ is still a binary variable but of a new type (in fact, we can use another symbol to denote it, like $l_{i j k}$ ), different from $z_{i j}$ and $a_{k}, b_{k}, c_{k}$ ? 2) In addition, considering the negation of inequality, should it be $z_{i j}=0 \Longrightarrow \bigvee_{k=1}^{4}\left(a_{k} i+b_{k} j+c_{k}>0\right)$, instead of $\geq 0$ ? Accordingly, the big-M constraint should be $-a_{k} i-b_{k} j-c_{k} < M_{i j 2} z_{i j k}$, but still $1-z_{i j} \leq \sum_{k}\left(1-z_{i j k}\right)$?

Comment: Yes, you can rename the additional binary variable $z_{ijk}$ to something else.  Yes, the strict negation of $\land ( \le 0)$ is $\lor ( > 0)$, but you cannot enforce strict inequalities in MILP.  Instead, you can enforce $\ge \epsilon$.